# Hive Python UDF error

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have a simple Python Script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
import datetime
for line in sys.stdin:
line = line.strip()
fname , lname = line.split('\t')
l_name = lname.lower()
print '\t'.join([fname, str(l_name)])
```

The Hive table Data looks like:

```
Akash   Gupta
Ashish  Agarwal
Aarav   Kedia
Rajesh  Lakhia
Sunita  Patel
Raj     Dutta
Nadeem  Siddiqui
```

And Table Structure is:

```
hive> desc fullName;
OK
fname                   string
lname                   string
```

I am adding my Python Script as:

```
add FILE /full-path-to-the-script/convertToLowerCase.py;
```

Now, I am running a Transform operation for the script:

```
SELECT TRANSFORM(fname, lname) USING 'python convertToLowerCase.py' AS (fname, l_name) FROM fullName;
```

But, the Map Reduce job is throwing error:
`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20003 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There was wrong with the Python Code.
The `Indentation of the For Loop`.

That solved the issue.